# Can anybody recommend me a Calculus Based General Chemistry textbook?

Tags: reference-request, books

I'm looking for a Calculus Based General Chemistry textbook. I checked Atkins Chemical Principals but I didn't liked it that much. I'd be awesome if I had some more options 
Thanks!

Comment: "Basic Chemistry" doesn't use much calculus. Calculus is more applicable to PChem. Specifically such topics as thermodynamics and kinetics.

Answer (score 1):

Most general chemistry courses include a chemical kinetics unit, where calculus would be appropriate (but is often avoided). Outside of that, there's not many places in general chemistry that calculus would be useful or appropriate (except of the nuclear chemistry section, which is mathematically equivalent to first order chemical kinetics).